# Python fatal error detected - bitmap "C:/LOG_29710.ico" not defined when running EXE (PyInstaller)

Tags: python

I know it was asked a lot but none helped me.
i have pyinstaller my code into exe file. This works great on my PC but on others it generates FATAL ERROR - cannot execute script.
Than - execute from other PC with command line to see what the issue is and it is breaking on below :

```
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "C:/LOG_29710.ico" not defined
```

This is the full path on my local PC but it seems to search for the icon in other PC same path which of course not exist.
What am I missing here?

by the way i have several images (not icons) with same path and same errors for all...I guess I need somekind of relative path or maybe put all of them in a specific place...

Answer (score 0):

You found the reason your self:

> This is the full path on my local PC but it seems to search for the icon in other PC same path which of course not exist. What am I missing here?

If the file isn't there, it can't be found. So put it there or, if you copied the whole project with icon to another PC, then make the path relative, so it can be found.

If the icon is in the same folder as the project, use:
`"LOG_29710.ico"` instead of full path `"C:\LOG..."`

Comment: This is true when executing from command line but when converting the whole script to EXE file - it breaks in another PC

Comment: @TheWiz: Make the path relative and if you convert to EXE, then include the icon to the filelist. Read more about pyinstaller doc.